# Regarding operations in a specific ring

Tags: ring-theory

So I have to answer this question:

Let U be the set of expressions of the form a + bu where a and b are real numbers.
The u is a formal symbol. We want to make U into a ring similar to how we defined **C**
as a ring, and we’d like u to satisfy the equation $u^2 = 2u - 2$. Provide the formulas we should use to define + and · in U.

Anybody understand what is meant by ''provide the formulas...''? Do I simply have to define addition and multiplication in U in the exact same way as in** C**? If not, what am I to do?

Answer (score 0):

If the ring operations have to satisfy the ring axioms, then there is only one way to define addition and multiplication:
$$
(a_1+b_1u)+(a_2+b_2u)=a_1+b_1u+a_2+b_2u=a_1+a_2+b_1u+b_2u=(a_1+a_2)+(b_1+b_2)u
$$
$$
(a_1+b_1u)\cdot(a_2+b_2u)=(a_1 a_2)+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)u+b_1b_2u^2=\cdots
$$
A subtle point is that you need to require that $u$ commutes with real numbers.

Another take is to consider the matrix representation and use the usual matrix operations:
$$
a+bu \leftrightarrow \pmatrix{ a & -2b \\ b & a+2b}
$$
This representation comes from the map $z \mapsto (a+bu)z$ in the basis $1,u$.

Comment: I assume that all this is true because, essentially, u = i + 1. So the way to derive these formulas is to substitute u with i + 1 in the definition of a + bu?

Comment: @JBuck, that's one way, but I think it is clearer to use the equation defining $u$, that is, $u^2 = 2u - 2$.