# Finding an isomorphic subring of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-isomorphism, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I'm struggling a fair amount with this exercise:

> Find a subring of $M(2,\mathbb{Q})$ which is isomorphic to a) $\mathbb{Q}$ x $ \mathbb{Q}$ b) $\mathbb{Q}$ c) $\mathbb{Q}[x]$/$x^2$

Now I know a subring must be a subgroup, must contain the elements $0,1$ and must be closed under multiplication. As we are looking for isomorphisms then they must also be ring homomorphisms and must be bijective.

I tried to come up with a random subring and attempt to prove it is an isomorphism. E.g $\left\{\left.\begin{matrix} 
a & b \\
c & 0 
\end{matrix}\right|a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$
is a subgroup of $M(2,\mathbb{Q})$ and then try and show it's an isomorphism. However I'm stuck here as I don't actually know how to go about finding these specific isomorphisms and I completely lose what I'm doing. Any help would be great.

Comment: "got very confused with the form of answer the question needs" - what exactly is your confusion? Terminology, notation, etc?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show your attempts and efforts to solve this question.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3128210/589

Comment: Why do you ask the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127413/find-a-sub-ring-of-m2-mathbbq-which-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbq) again and again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we're talking about a ring homomorphism.

If we're looking for something isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, note that we can get the integers by adding up copies of $1$. Then adding $n$ copies of $\frac1n$ gets us $1$; we're going to need all the scalar multiples of whatever we're mapping to $1$.

So, the subring we want to map to $\mathbb{Q}$ will consist of the scalar multiples of some $A$, and that $A$ will be mapped to $1$. Now, it's time to look at multiplication. What can we say about multiplication by $A$?

Comment: ah okay that makes a lot more sense thank you, would it be very similar then when checking if its isomorphic to another ring, like $\mathbb{Q}$ x $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Similar, yes. Any ring homomorphism will also be a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**
Start with part b), and take the scalar multiples of the identity matrix. 
For a), consider the diagonal matrices. 
Finally for c), map $1$ to the identity matrix and map $x$ to a nontrivial matrix $M$ that satisfies $M^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints, but if i wasn't given those, how would one normally come about thinking that up?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Write the three rings in the form $\{ a + b u : a,b \in \mathbb Q \}$ with $u$ satisfying a quadratic equation, $u^2=cu+d$. Then identity the ring with a matrix subring using the matrix representation:
$$
a+bu \leftrightarrow \pmatrix{ a & bd \\ b & a+bc}
$$
This representation comes from the map $z \mapsto (a+bu)z$ in the basis $1,u$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126813/regarding-operations-in-a-specific-ring

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it