# $\operatorname{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$ as a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Prove that the set of $2 \times 2$-matrices of the form
> $$
> \left(\begin{array}{ll}
> a & b \\
> c & d
> \end{array}\right), \quad a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}
> $$
> with the usual matrix addition and multiplication is a non-commutative ring (that is, the multiplication is not commutative). Can you find conditions on $a, b, c, d$ to make it into a field?

I already did the first part and showed that this is a non-commutative ring. Now, I'm trying to find the conditions to make it be a field. For this, we just have to find the multiplicative inverse, which from linear algebra we know that a $2\times 2$ matrix is invertible if $\operatorname{det} (A) \neq 0$, which means $ad-bc \neq 0$ or equivalently, one row isn't a multiple of the other. Now, I just want to know that if this is enough!?

Comment: Is the set of invertible matrices closed under addition?

Comment: The conditions $a=d$ and $b=c=0$ make it a field...

Comment: Cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028371/complex-number-isomorphic-to-certain-2-times-2-matrices)

Comment: @Thorgott Oh! No! You're right...

Comment: @dan_fulea what about $a=d$, and $b=-c$?

Comment: You also have to make sure your set is commutative, if you want it to be a field.

Comment: @Zenocosini That works too. There are [other choices](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2840174/81360) that yield the same field up to isomorphism.

Comment: As the question is not well defined, one could also say e.g. $a = d \in \Bbb Q, b = c = 0$ and so on. Basically you are asked which kind of fields can be embedded in the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3128210/589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally did:

if $a=d$ and $b=-c$, the set $SM_2(\mathbb{R})=\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\\ \end{pmatrix} \bigg| a, b \in \mathbb{R}\bigg\}$ turns into a field because:

$SM_2(\mathbb{R})$ is commutative, because:
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c\\ \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} ac-bd & -ad-bc \\ bc+ad & -bd+ac\\ \end{pmatrix}
       \\ &= \begin{pmatrix} c & -d \\ d & c\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\\ \end{pmatrix}
       \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}

The multiplicative inverse exists and is the inverse of matrix $A$, because $\det(A)=a^2-(-b)b=a^2+b^2\neq 0$, so $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a\\ \end{pmatrix}$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
       \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} & \frac{b}{a^2+b^2} \\ \frac{-b}{a^2+b^2} & \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\\ \end{pmatrix} 
       &= \begin{pmatrix} \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2} & \frac{ab-ba}{a^2+b^2} \\ \frac{ba-ab}{a^2+b^2} & \frac{b^2+a^2}{a^2+b^2}\\ \end{pmatrix}
       \\ &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}
       \end{aligned}
       \end{equation*}

Thus, $SM_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a field. Plus, it cannot be an ordered field. For this, consider $\varphi: SM_2(\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\varphi\left( \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a\\
\end{pmatrix}\right)=a+bi$. We have:

For any $A, B \in SM_2(\mathbb{R})$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
           \varphi(AB)&= \varphi\left( \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
c & -d \\ d & c\\
\end{pmatrix}\right)= \varphi\left( \begin{pmatrix} ac-bd & -ad-bc \\ bc+ad & -bd+ac\\ \end{pmatrix} \right) \\
&= (ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i= ac+adi+bci+bdi^2\\
&= a(c+di)+bi(c+di)= (a+bi)(c+di)\\
&= \varphi\left( \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a\\
\end{pmatrix}\right) \varphi\left(\begin{pmatrix}
c & -d \\ d & c\\
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\varphi(A)\varphi(B)
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
So, $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

For any $A, B \in SM_2(\mathbb{R})$, assume that $\varphi(A)=\varphi(B)$, then $a+bi=c+di$, so $(a-c)+(b-d)i=0$, and hence, $a=c$ and $b=d$ which means that $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a\\
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
c & -d \\ d & c\\
\end{pmatrix} =B$. So, $\varphi$ is injective.

Now, let $a+bi\in \mathbb{C}$. Then, since we defined matrices in $SM_2(\mathbb{R})$ to be all the $2\times 2$ matrices with $a=d$, and $b=-c$, there exists $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a\\
\end{pmatrix} \in SM_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\varphi\left( \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\ b & a\\
\end{pmatrix}\right)=a+bi$.

So $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Hence, $SM_2(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ and since no order can be defined on $\mathbb{C}$, the aforementioned field cannot take any orders as well.